# I can run with `iex` in terminal, but it doesn't work in my umbrella project

Tags: elixir, asdf-vm

I could went into iex mode with command 'iex', but in my umbrella project, what i got is `asdf: No version set for command mix`.

```
➜  ~ iex
Erlang/OTP 21 [erts-10.3] [source] [64-bit] [smp:12:12] [ds:12:12:10] [async-threads:1] [hipe]

Interactive Elixir (1.8.2) - press Ctrl+C to exit (type h() ENTER for help)
iex(1)>
```

but in project:

```
➜  ticket_service git:(get-tickets-count-166053245) iex
asdf: No version set for command iex
you might want to add one of the following in your .tool-versions file:

elixir 1.8.2-otp-21
➜  ticket_service git:(get-tickets-count-166053245) mix compile
asdf: No version set for command mix
you might want to add one of the following in your .tool-versions file:

elixir 1.8.2-otp-21
```

BTW, the project is cloned from my github repo, i can even create an new umbrella project and run mix commend everywhere except in my project. It seems like the `asdf` config is not went into effect in project.

Comment: I change my laptop into mac recently, and the elixir and erlang is installed by `asdf`

Comment: and the asdf version is 0.7.2

Comment: Do you have a `.tool-versions` file in your project? If so, what is its contents? How about if you do `asdf local elixir 1.8.2`?

Answer (score 1):

> and the asdf version is 0.7.2

I encountered the same problem on `OSX` when I installed a new version of `elixir` then updated `asdf`.

```
~/elixir_programs$ asdf --version
v0.7.2
```

The following was in .tool_versions (which I never touched):

```
~$ cat .tool-versions 
elixir 1.8.2
erlang 20.3
```

This fixed the problem for me:

```
$ asdf reshim elixir
```

If that doesn't work, see this [asdf issue](https://github.com/asdf-vm/asdf/issues/488) about the problem.

Comment: I don't know how, i tried `reshim`, but it doesn't work. Anyway thanks bro.

Comment: @pengfeixu, Sorry.  If you answer the questions posted in the comments under your question, you might get some additional help.

Answer (score 1):

Although i solved this problem yesterday, I do not remember how it was solved clearly. But the thought at the beginning is:

1. install elixir with a version you wanted;
2. get into you project;
3. run `asdf current` to see which version of erlang is elixir needed
4. then to install the needed erlang